# Function binding normative

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and MVVM and am going through an example on [Microsoft's site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx), however, I don't see how the binding is done. In the example linked, there's this piece of code:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private PartInventoryViewModel viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new PartInventoryViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void PartSearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.GetParts();
    }
}
```

Apparently:

> It notifies the ViewModel instance when the user clicks the PartSearchButton.

But how? There's no binding in the XAML above for the `PartSearchButton` in the example. Is it a normative that if you name your function YourButtonName_Clicked() it will trigger when the button is clicked? Or does it become a listener if you create the function with the `(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` arguments? Or is there some XAML which this tutorial is not showing, where the binding occurs?

Thank you for your answer, sorry if it's a newb one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft is not showing all the code that is necessary here. Basically all that this code does is setting the `DataContext` to a newly instantiated ViewModel. The `PartSearchButton_Click`  is a simple Click-Event-Handler that should look something like this in your XAML-file:

```
<Button Click="PartSearchButton_Click">Search</Button>
```

The whole binding thing is happening in these 2 lines of the datagrid in your xaml file:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPart, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

This is telling the DataGrid that it should look for a public property called `Parts` in the current DataContext. You set the DataContext to a new instance of `PartInventoryViewModel`, so there needs to be a public property `Parts` somewhere in there. I guess the `PartInventoryViewModel` class will be explained a bit further down on the Microsofts site.

Answer (score 0):

The XAML snippets from your link are effectively missing that event handler.

The `<source>_<event>` guideline is the convention for naming event handlers, but by no means the function gets automatically bound to the corresponding event; you have to add the handler either programmatically or in XAML.

That said, associating application logic to buttons is usually done in WPF by means of commands instead of event handlers. The view model exposes a property of type `ICommand`, anf the view binds the `Command` dependency property of a `Button` (or other controls)  to it. How that command is implemented under the hood is completely irrelevant to the view.